# how to get the output of an execution

Tags: ansible

I have next play:

```
  - hosts: grupo1
    tasks:
    - name: tareas deployment
      block:
   
        - name: role Tibco
          import_role:
            name: TIBCO
          vars:
            pordefinir: 'pordefinir'
            salida_descarga: "{{ output_descarga.uid }}"
            circuitos: "{{ lista_circuito.msg }}"    
      rescue:
        - name: Detectar se ha producido errores en la ejecucion de la parte de despliegue
          import_tasks: /home/javi/gestionErrores.yml
```

in:

```
      - name: role Tibco
      import_role:
        name: TIBCO
      vars:
        pordefinir: 'pordefinir'
        salida_descarga: "{{ output_descarga.uid }}"
        circuitos: "{{ lista_circuito.msg }}"
```

I execute an script and I store the output in a variable called salida_postscript

```
    - name: lanzando primer comando post script con el usuario javi
  become: true
  become_user: "{{ usuarioAplicacion }}"
  shell: /home/javi/script/tibco/postscript.sh {{ build }} {{ entorno }} {{ circuito }}
  register: salida_postscript
```

If I execute the play I can see the output of salida_postscript

```
fatal: [cslave1]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "/home/javi/script/tibco/postscript.sh 1.2.3.4 DESARROLLO CIR_TIBCO_EI_PP_PR", "delta": "0:00:01.009764", "end": "2021-06-01 01:09:45.658169", "msg": "non-zero return code", **"rc": 1,** "start": "2021-06-01 01:09:44.648405", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

the latest task of the play does not recognize that variable, it is undefined

```
this is the output:
fatal: [cmaster]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: {{ salida_postscript }}: 'salida_postscript' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to be in '/home/javi/roles/finalizar_master/tasks/main.yml': line 2, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n---\n- name: Actualizar fin de la ejecucion en JIRA\n  ^ here\n"}
```

Is it possible that the output of a task can be used in another task?
How Can i do it?

regards
Javi

Answer (score 0):

It depends if the output itself is considered as a fail or not, if you do not want the playbook to halt you will need to make sure that the output will be either not an exit code with an error or you set the ignore_errors flag on the shell task to true.

Comment: I would like my play to continue. The goal of the latest step is to write the rc of the execution in a file

Comment: then the ignore_errors on the shell task is the way forward :)

Comment: I add ignore_error
- name: lanzando primer comando post script con el usuario javi
  become: true
  become_user: "{{ usuarioAplicacion }}"
  shell: /home/javi/script/tibco/postscript.sh {{ build }} {{ entorno }} {{ circuito }}
  register: salida_postscript
  ignore_errors: yes
  
but I get the same error:
{"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: {{ salida_postscript }}

Comment: anyway, although the rc is 0, I get the same error